# Access to path denied - IIS express - upload file -Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I know this error maybe very popular and there are many people asking about it. I have read through other threads but can not seem to find a solution applicable to my scenario.
I am new to ASP.NET programming, am using vs 2013 ultimate, IIS express on my laptop with Windows 8.1. 
I have created a new website using WebForms and I was testing the upload function to my local machine running IIS express that came with VS2013.
My code behind is as simple as

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class MyWebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            string name = TextBox1.Text;
            string type = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            string filename = FileUpload1.FileName;
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Content"));
        }
    }
}
```

Ran it and got this error:

```
{"Access to the path 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\WebSites\\WebFormDemo\\Content' is denied."}
```

I understand that it is an unauthorized access due to lack of privilege, but my question is how do I give access to my application? I have admin right on my machine, run it locally so the firewall should not be an issue. Some threads suggested to go to IIS manager and adjust the right to DefaultPool but I do not think I have InetMgr on my Windows 8.1,

How do I solve the unauthorized access for my case?

Comment: You need to give permissions to that folder to the account that the application is running under (not your account).  I believe that for asp.net applications that's the asp.net user/identity.

Comment: @Knight: Thanks for the advice. I am admin of my machine, I can browse into the directory with no problem. Can you clarify what asp.net user/identity were you referring to? my login to windows, my ad account or is there a specific asp.net user id that I have to create or existed?

Comment: I think that there is a special ASPNET user that asp.net runs applications under by default.  I'm not 100% on that, and there of course could be other reasons.  If you published it and ran it in IIS (rather than through Visual Studio) you'd need to find APPPOOL user that the application ran under (APPPOOL/DefaultAppPool by default) and give them the necessary permissions.  I believe the same is true when you run it from Visual Studio - I'm just not 100% sure on the user.